# Displaying text and icons on the same line in mobile version

Tags: css, mobile, text, icons

I would love to display individual icons (made with wordpress) and text on the same line. It's looking ok on the desktop screens but not on mobile phones. Please, take a look at the image attachment. Is there any possible solution with css codes? Thank you, guys.

Regards

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can use image as a background property or using flex box. Could i have the HTML code to look after it.

Comment: maybe you just need "white-space: nowrap" but also its better to see your code. could you please share it?

Comment: Could you provide HTML & CSS code. Then easy to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both written in div tag like...

icon
 


 text

just change there css property display: block; to display: inline-block;
Same CSS works if they are in

tag also.

Hope this helps...